# How to write compound statement for database query in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

To design password-username authentication, I tried to retrieve 'salt' from table(membership) and appended it to password. then encrypted the combination with SHA256. But when I wrote the validate() function as below, an error came out that

> Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_driver could not be converted to
>   string

code:

```
public function validate(){

  $this->db->where('username',$this->input->post('username'));
  $salt=(string)$this->db->select('salt');
  $this->db->where('password',hash('sha256',$this->input->post('password').$salt));
  $query=$this->db->get('membership');

  if($query->num_rows()==1){ return TRUE; }
}
```

How to fix the problem? I'm using codeigniter 2.1.2. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create two seperate queries:

```
public function validate(){

    $this->db->select('salt');
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username', TRUE));
    $salt = (string) $this->db->get('membership')->row()->salt;

    $this->db->where('password', 
                    hash('sha256', $this->input->post('password', TRUE). $salt));
    $query=$this->db->get('membership'); 

    if($query->num_rows()==1) { 
         return TRUE; 
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Could this not be done using MySQL's hashing? i.e. `$this->db->where('Password', 'SHA2(concat(' . $this->db->escape($this->db->post('password', true)) . ', salt), 256)', null);`?